# Unable to load BigBlueButton in iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, bigbluebutton

I am using a custom BBB installation for use in my Angular App. I am calling the join request in an iframe with `redirect` set to `true`. Everything was working fine with BBB 2.0 but after I have updated it to 2.2, I am getting an error `401 Unauthorised due to missing credentials`.

However, if I make the same request in a new tab, it loads the meeting.

There is another weird behaviour. It works fine even in an iframe on Chrome in Mac.

What changed with 2.2? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, I added

```
 allowRequestsWithoutSession=true
```

in */usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties* (then remember to restart BBB with *bbb-conf --restart*)

Then I used this iframe to enable all features (screen sharing, full screen...)

```
 <IFRAME allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; display-capture *;" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals allow-forms" style='width:100%;height:100%;border:0' scrolling="no"></IFRAME>
```

Note: the page with the iframe must be on a https website otherwise you'll get only a dark blue empty screen.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be using chromium, chrome or any chromium based browser?

I believe this is related to google rolling out the [Same-Site-By-Default (anti?-)feature](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592) to a fraction of their users. I can reproduce your issues by enabling that feature. I believe you won't experience these issues anymore if you visit chrome://flags/ and set **SameSite by default cookies** to **Disabled**.

If that helps then you'll have to make sure BBB sends the correct set-cookie-headers in order to solve the problem for other chrome browsers with "SameSite by default cookies" enabled. Addin `SameSite=none` to the Set-Cookie header should work.

Probably the easiest way to solve this would be to run the website containing the iframe and the bbb instance on the same site. [This post explains which two domains qualify as "same site"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428727).

Comment: Disabling SameSite by default worked but now I need to modify the cookie being sent by BBB, since I can't expect every user to apply this fix for their browsers. Combing through the code base, no luck so far.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make sure to run bbb and your app on the same site. Same site is when their URLs have the same second-level domain – provided that the 2ld is not on the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/)

Comment: You tag the cookie in the html5 nginx conf file inside location /html5.....  like proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none";