# BigBlueButton HTML5 client shows error in iFrame

Tags: google-chrome, join, bigbluebutton

I want to show BBB HTML5 client inside of my page. As far as I know, the only way, how to do this, is using iframe. Following this guide - https://www.bigbluemeeting.com/docs/iframe - I declare iframe like this

```
<iframe class="meeting_screen" id="meetingFrame" width="100%" height="700" allow="camera *;microphone *;display-capture *;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I create the meeting using PHP API and I get valid join URL. I wait suggested 5 seconds and I set iframe src:

```
$("#meetingFrame").attr("src",meetingURL);
```

It works great using FireFox. Unfortunately, Chrome shows this error:

[image]

In case, I open the URL in new window:

```
window.open(meetingURL,'meeting');
```

it works with both - Chrome and Firefox. I believe it has something to do with Chrome cross origin protection ( BBB server runs on different computer than web server ). Solution proposed here [Unable to load BigBlueButton in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193093/unable-to-load-bigbluebutton-in-iframe) as the second answer works for me, but I don't won't my server to allow requests without session.

Is there a way, how to make it working under Chrome?